# Anime or cartoon where one main character has a pan as a weapon and can summon a giant roast chicken

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, music-video

I only remember watching the original soundtrack video of this anime/cartoon, not sure whether it's Japanese/Korean/Chinese animation...

In the original soundtrack video, there are three main characters who seems to be running away from enemies (pandas? I think). One of the characters (not sure if they were a girl or a boy) has an ability to summon a giant roast chicken from the sky (complete with a plate) with a swing from their pan.

At the end of the video they successfully escaped using an ability? One of the other characters seems to be summoning a big bird of flying creatures.

In the original soundtrack video, the singers were three girls (real girls).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Please don't use abbreviations like "ost" without explaining them.  Also, can you be a bit more specific about when you watched this?  How did they escape using a giant roast chicken on a plate?

Comment: What's "a big bird of flying creatures"?

Comment: Thanks for the info, 1. I watched this opening video song like, 10 years ago. 2. They did not escape using giant roast chicken, but it was a technique by one of the character fight the enemies, and they escaped by using the technique of the other character that seems has the ability to summon big bird. 3. I dont really remember what kind of species it is... So i just kinda guessed it as a bird...

Comment: Swing a pan and get a roast chicken? Sounds like my kind of weapon! mmmmm... hungry....